# How to implement a system-level shortcut in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I need some shortcut keys in my WPF application. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060893/implement-short-cut-keys-in-wpf-application) post.

However this link seems to be about application/window level in WPF. For example, the shortcut key is only working in a specific window.

However, what I need is for system&global level. For example, the application is launched but it has been minimized. When my mouse is focused on some other placed in desktop, I click "ctrl+alt+a", then the application will be maximized(or any other operations will be down in the application).

How could I implement such system-level shortcut keys?

Comment: Look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftletter-using-wpf-and-ne

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C This might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@XAMLLOver gives me the correct solution.

Others who needs the global short cut key could check the article below.

[Solution for system-level short cut key](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)